# Using Active Objects and BLOBs

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse

I am in a group of people who are creating a Defect Tracking program as a project.  We have been using Active Objects and have run into some issues.  Currently maximum file size for the blob is approx. 2Mb but we want to be able to increase it up to 2Gb.  We currently have been looking at many sites and have not been able to find out how to increase the size.  We are currently storing the blob as an array of bytes.  Our current error says, Packet for Query is too large?  We don't know how to set the variable, and we don't know how to set it using AO.  We are programming this in Java, too.  We are wondering if anyone has a solution to this problem.

Thanks for the Help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a mysql issue.  You will need to edit your mysql configuration (/etc/mysql/my.cnf on Linux) and alter the value of max_allowed_packet.